# Where can I find annual temperature data for every city and town in the US and Australia?

Tags: data

Where can I find yearly annual averaged temperature data for every city and town in the US and Australia for a heatmap?

links are good

Comment: Just for clarification, are you looking for point data, or can you work with raster data as well?

Comment: you can use whatever you like, probably best to use whatever is easier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The resource at GOSIC:
http://gosic.org/content/gcos-surface-network-gsn-data-access

It's not every town and city - but it's the most comprehensive coverage for international comparison.

Of course, you could go big and get the data straight from the University of East Anglia:
http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/temperature/#datdow

But be prepared for a *steep* learning curve....

There's NOAA coverage for detail in the USA:
http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/land-based-station-data/quality-controlled-local-climatological-data-qclcd

and for Australia the link is:
http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/change/

... have fun coloring in things Purple!

Comment: there is **never** a steep learning curve. just bad data, bad transmition of info, and bad user-friendly

Comment: while other answers are ok, i like how the best answer is from the lowest reps ^_^

Comment: Long time stalker, only recent contributor!

Answer (score 4):

Try [Worldclim](http://www.worldclim.org/) it's a raster set, with several clim average measurements from 1950 - 2000.

Answer (score 2):

For Australia, climate data is available from the [Bureau of Meteorology](http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/data).

Answer (score 1):

The **Weather Underground Weather API**

has the option (free) for historical weather is coverage more than US and Australia

There is a pricing structure if your are doing more than 500 API calls a day.

But worth looking in into:

http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/pricing.html

Answer (score 1):

I've used PRISM data before:
http://www.prism.oregonstate.edu/

Some of it's free, some you have to $$$